# NGINX as reverse proxy for http and ssh

Tags: nginx, ssh, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up NGINX as a reverse proxy for HTTP and SSL.

Here is a configuration in **/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**:

```
upstream sample-client {
  server sample-client:3006;
}

upstream sample-server {
  server sample-server:3000;
}

upstream ssh {
  server sample-server:22;
}

server {
  listen 80;
       
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://sample-client;
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://sample-server;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
  }
     
  error_page 405 =200 @405; 

  location @405 {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      proxy_pass http://sample-client; 
  }  
}

server {
  listen 22;
  proxy_pass ssh;
}
```

But it throws the next error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:60
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: For performing a proxy_pass for ssh you will need to use the stream module instead of the http module. Otherwise the configuration will be the same as when trying to proxy http traffic.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html

Answer (score 0):

proxy_pass directive should be inside location block
described in https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

> To pass a request to an HTTP proxied server, the
> `proxy_pass` directive is specified inside a
> `location` .

this means that the second server location must include a location block
probably similar to

location / {
proxy_pass ssh;
}